# construct a matrix in Matlab without using iterative functions

Tags: matrices, matlab

I have 
$r= \mbox{randi}(1000,100,1)$. I want to construct a matrix $A(i,j)$ with the following relation:
\begin{cases}
A(i,j)=1 & \mbox{if} r(i)=j \\     
A(i,j)=0 & \mbox{otherwise}    
\end{cases}
P.s: I should do it with some vector/matrix operations. I can use “ones” and “zeros” functions. I cannot use iterative functions such as “for”, “while”, … or any other specific functions.

Comment: Did you deliberately write $r(i)=j$ (which is the same as $r(i,1) = j$) or did you mean $r(i,j)=j$? In the latter case, try `A = r==1:100;` if you have Matlab R2016 or later. Otherwise `A = r==repmat(1:100,1000,1);`.

Comment: I meant that the random variable of each row of r will be the column number of  matrix A(i,j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what you aimed to describe:

```
r = randi(1000,100,1);

l = 1000.*[0:length(r)-1] + r';

A = zeros(1000,100);
A(l) = 1;
A = A';

spy(A)

% for comparison

B = zeros(1000,100);
for i = 1:length(r)
    B(s(i),r(i)) = 1;
end

spy(B)
```

I hope it helps.